# time cakephp 3 save in the database with different value

Tags: php, angularjs, cakephp

well I'm working receiving time but when this save in the database is different, if I send 8:00 pm in the database save with 12:00 am, for all cases with +4 hours.

Receiving data from a form I get this from the console:

```
Thu Jan 01 1970 08:00:00 GMT-0400 (Hora estándar oeste, Sudamérica)
```

I'm working with angular js backend with cakephp 3:

```
 public function add()
        {
            $data = ['result' => 'fail', 'id' => 'null'];
            $errors = $this->Shifts->validator()->errors($this->request->getData());
            if(empty($errors))
            {
                $shifts = $this->Shifts->newEntity($this->request->getData());
                $date_entrada = strtotime($this->request->getData('hora_entrada'));
                $date_salida = strtotime($this->request->getData('hora_salida'));
                $shifts->hora_entrada = date('H:i:s', $date_entrada);
                $shifts->hora_salida = date('H:i:s', $date_salida);
                if ($this->Shifts->save($shifts))
                {
                    $data = ['result' => 'success', 'id' => $shifts->id];
                }
            } else {

                $data['error'] = $errors;
            }
            $this->set(compact('data'));
            $this->set('_serialize', ['data']);
        }
```

Comment: I think that is because the data base is set to use UTC timezone, you should be in a timezone UTC-4  so to keep correct track of the date it adds 4 hours. The inverse action should happen when fetching the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your config/bootsrap.php add the following...

```
/*
 * Set server timezone to UTC. You can change it to another timezone of your
 * choice but using UTC makes time calculations / conversions easier.
 */
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

check in this list where is the time zone you want to set...

http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php

Regards